# Have a object in background as a variable, how to update values (parse.com)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So `var touser:PFObject` is in the background along with its values, how do i update the value of a array of touser?

Ex. `touser.objectforkey("names")` is an array of names that had been queried when the user entered the `ViewController`, how do I update with the current names in that array (others may have added their name to the array and a button shows the values of the array.).

Comment: Request an update from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly.

You want to update your names in the PFObject?

```
var touser: PFObject
touser.objectForKey("names") as [String] //Assuming 'names' is [String]
let newNames = ["A", "B"]
touser.setObject(newNames, forKey: "names")
touser.saveEventually()
```